# How to define the force at the base of an oceanic crust

Tags: geophysics, geodynamics, isostasy

In the book of [Turcotte and Schubert, Geodynamics](https://books.google.com/books?id=-nCHlVuJ4FoC&pg=PA80&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) I'm trying to solve problem 2.8.

The pressure in the water, in the oceanic crust, and in the mantle beneath the oceanic crust are (from equation 2.19, page 78) is

$$p_w = \rho_w g y , \quad  0 \le y \le h_{w}$$
$$p_{oc} = \rho_w g h_{w} + \rho_{oc} g (y - h_{w}) , \quad  h_{w} \le y \le h_{w}+h_{oc}$$

$$p_m = \rho_w g h_w + \rho_{oc} g h_{oc} + \rho_m g (y-h_w-h_{oc}), \quad  h_w+h_{oc} \le y \le h_{cc}$$
I should integrate that to find the force at the base of the oceanic crust.

we know that

$$F=∫_0^b pdy=ρg∫_0^by dy=0.5 ρgb^2$$

so

$$F_m=∫_{h_w+h_{oc}}^{h_{cc}} p_mdy$$

then I tried this

$$F_m=∫_{h_w+h_{oc}}^{h_{cc}}\rho_w g h_w + \rho_{oc} g h_{oc} + \rho_m g (y-h_w-h_{oc})dy$$

and it didn't provide the proper result, so i tried to integrate all the pressures:

$$F_w=∫_0^{h_{w}}\rho_w g ydy = 0.5 \rho_w g h_{w}^2$$
$$F_{oc} = ∫_{h_w}^{h_{w}+h_{oc}} \rho_w g h_{w} + \rho_{oc} g (y - h_{w})dy= \rho_w g h_{w}+0.5 \rho_{oc} g (h_{w}+h_{oc})^2 - 0.5 \rho_{oc} g h_{w}^2 - \rho_{oc} g h_{w}$$

I did the same for the last integral and added them all together: $$F_o = F_w+F_{oc}+F_m$$

but I still don't get the same final expression as equation 2.20, page 78.

Can someone give me a hint to solve the integral? are the limits of my integral correct? Am I adding the right forces together?

Comment: I deleted the previous post because I thought I had found the answer, but actually not !

Comment: I wish I had brought the book with me, and my solutions, as I've definitely done this problem.  I will try and get a book from the library of the university I am visiting and answer this tomorrow.

Comment: That would be great !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach of adding all the forces together is correct. You have a mistake in in the solution of the $F_{oc}$ integral, though.
You forgot to integrate the terms $\rho_{w}gh_{w}$ and $-\rho_{oc}gh_{w}$

It should read:

$F_{oc} = ... = \rho_{w}gh_{w}(h_{w}+h_{oc}) - \rho_{w}gh_{w}h_{w} + 0.5\rho_{oc}g(h_{w}+h_{oc})^{2} - 0.5\rho_{oc}gh_{w}^{2} - \rho_{oc}gh_{w}(h_{w}+h_{oc}) + \rho_{oc}gh_{w}h_{w} $

You have to keep this in mind for $F_{M}$ as well.